# If $G$ is a group, how is the subgroup $2G$ defined?

Tags: group-theory, definition, elliptic-curves

I am reading Mordell's theorem from Silverman and Tate's book. It uses the notation "$2 \Gamma$" for any commutative group $\Gamma$. Does it mean the group $\{g+g\mid g\in \Gamma \}$?

**Theorem 3.5 (Descent Theorem)**. *Let $\Gamma$ be a commutative group and suppose that there is a function  $h : \Gamma \to [0, \infty)$ with the following three properties:*

(a) *For every real number M, the set $\{P \in \Gamma : h(P) \leq M\}$ is finite.*

(b) *For every $P_0 \in \Gamma$ there is a constant $\kappa_0$ so that $h(P+P_0) \leq 2h(P) + \kappa_0$ for all $P \in \Gamma$.*

(c) *There is a constant $\kappa$ so that $h(2P) \geq 4h(P)- \kappa $ for all $P \in \Gamma$.*

*Suppose further that*

(d) *The subgroup $2\Gamma$ has finite index in $\Gamma$.*

*Then, $\Gamma$ is finitely generated.*

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Probably, and all the more if the book uses the additive notation for commutative groups. It's the standard notation for $\Bbb Z$-modules.

Comment: For an abelian group $A$, the expression $n a = a + \dots + a (n \text{ times})$ is an element of $A$, and in fact $\{ n a : a \in A\} \equiv n A$ forms a subgroup.  Proof that.  Let $n = 2, \ A = \Gamma$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742) for why you should **not** post images that contain essential parts of the question you are asking about. Please take the image out and type in the material.